# htaccess 301 redirect, non-www and www old domain include homepage

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

We have setup the old domain to redirect to the new domain. The below redirect works fine for all pages and folders, however the homepage is not redirecting as should.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^turkish\-property\-world\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.turkish\-property\-world\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/propertysaleturkey\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

All pages redirect correctly, except http://www.turkish-property-world.com does not redirect.

How can we include the homepage to redirect as well ?

Comment: What do you mean by "homepage not redirectin"? do u have any other rules in htaccess?

Comment: I just noticed that non-www redirects, however www does not redirect using above code. no other code in htaccess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?turkish-property-world\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://propertysaleturkey.com/$1 [NC,R=301,L]
```

Or you can also use RedirectMatch directive of apache **mod_alias** :

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(.*)$ http://propertysaleturkey.com/$1
```

Don't forget to clear your browser's cache before testing the above solutions.

Comment: great. these work well http://www.propertysaleturkey.com and http://propertysaleturkey.com both domains redirect correctly.